# Can not add content to panels

Tags: 7, nodes, panels

Environment:

- Drupal 7
- Modules: Page manager, Devel generate, panels in-Place Editor, Panels, CTools, jquery-module

I defined a 3 column design but I can not add any content to any panel (superior, left side, middle column, right side...)

[image]

Any idea what it can be?

Comment: Have you tried this with a built in layout?

Comment: No, what you mean?. What I've seen is a dot next to every area (Superior, left side...) on tutorials that I do not have here and I can add content to these areas

Comment: "I defined a 3 column design". I'm asking if you've tried to use a build in layout instead of your own, to rule out that your layout is the problem. The gears should normally be there, so it must be something you've added/changed that's removed them.

Answer (score 0):

So it turned out to be a jquery version problem.

Here is how I sort it out.

I have installed the jQuery Update module with version 1.10 selected and I had to change it to version jQuery Version 1.7 and all the gotchas faded away.

I hope this help to anyone else!

(Module jquery_update)